# "What type of cell this tissue made of?"-- is this how to construct the question?

Tags: sentence-structure

I just want to know if this sentence structure sounds Ok.

> What type of cell this tissue made of?

I'm suspecting this because I didn't find any sentence like that on Google.

Comment: How it sounds doesn't matter. It isn't correct regardless.

Comment: @Dory When in doubt, think of its declarative sentence first, e.g. *This tissue is made up of [blah blah blah]*. Let's say that you want to ask what kind or type of cell [blah blah blah] is; you convert the declarative sentence into a question: *What type of cell is this tissue made up of?* -- I'm sure there must be a similar ELL question with some good answers somewhere, but I don't know what question it is.

Answer (score 1):

What type of cell this tissue made of?

Please look at the following sentences to know the correct construction of this sentence:

This chair is made of oak.

What type of wood is this chair made of?

This tissue is made of muscle cells?

The OP's correct sentence should be:

What type of cells is this tissue made of?